# How to hide the "action" extension

Tags: struts2, struts-config

When user makes login then on `success` browser redirect to

`http://appname.com/main.action`
How can I make so that adress line will looks like `http://appname.com/main`

```xml
<action name="login"
    class="user.action.LoginAction" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        main
    </result>
    <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Going from a local testing environment to live site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391423/going-from-a-local-testing-environment-to-live-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the following property in the struts.xml :

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
```

You can set different extensions, or no extension at all, that is specified with the comma for a reason, as you can read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629951/1654265).

It's generally used together with [Advanced Wildcard Mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097360/1654265),to create user-friendly pretty URLs.

Comment: Hi Andrea, i want hide the .action extension using struts 1 . Can u help me how to do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032331/how-to-remove-do-prefix-from-url-in-struts1

Comment: Hi Andrea , I have put like that only even though its not working still .do extension is appear in the URL

Comment: How can the `.do` extension keep appearing if [you wrote that your current extension is `.action`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58553020/1654265)?? Please, read _every_ sentence from _every_ answer (_including_ the comments) from that Q&A, don't just copy-paste. That said, my religion imposes me not to discuss Struts1 anymore, sorry :]